# gwt developer tools IE8 plugin install problem on Windows 7

Tags: gwt, windows-7, ie-developer-tools

Today I started testing a gwt application on a new notebook with Windows 7. Testing with Firefox went OK, then I started it in IE8. The "Development Mode requires the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin" comes up, fine, click on Download. A moment (and a download) later, an IE security warning window comes up ("Do you want to run this software?"), click Run. BTW, I started IE as Administrator...

Then a nice progress bar is displayed, with an "Initializing..." the text above, and it stays stuck forever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, I think the installer isn't registering the plugin dll correctly. You can do this manually in a command prompt via:

`regsvr32.exe "C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Google\Google Web
Toolkit\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll"`

This is based on a post on the [GWT groups](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/cbd4066ec41ecee6?hl=en).